# Trying to Filter XML using XPath

Tags: c#, linq, xslt, xpath, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to filter an XML file using XPath.  The XPath that I'm using is definitely filtering to the data that I want, but I'm just not sure how to filter the file overall.

Here's the sample XML file:

```
<fields>
    <field name='F'>
        <field name='0'><value>F.0 stuff</value></field>
        <field name='1'><value>F.1 stuff</value></field>
        <field name='2'><value>F.2 stuff</value></field>
    </field>
    <field name='B'>
        <field name='0'><value>B.0 stuff</value></field>
        <field name='1'><value>B.1 stuff</value></field>
        <field name='2'><value>B.2 stuff</value></field>
        <field name='3'><value>B.3 stuff</value></field>
    </field>
</fields>
```

Here's the desired output:

```
<fields>
    <field name='F'>
        <field name='1'><value>F.1 stuff</value></field>
        <field name='2'><value>F.2 stuff</value></field>
    </field>
    <field name='B'>
        <field name='3'><value>B.3 stuff</value></field>
    </field>
</fields>
```

The solution does not necessarily have to be solved by XPath, but since this is a .NET application, .NET APIs would be appreciated!  The following code can be cut and pasted into [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net) with no edits to see what I'm trying to do.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"
<fields>
    <field name='F'>
        <field name='0'><value>F.0 stuff</value></field>
        <field name='1'><value>F.1 stuff</value></field>
        <field name='2'><value>F.2 stuff</value></field>
    </field>
    <field name='B'>
        <field name='0'><value>B.0 stuff</value></field>
        <field name='1'><value>B.1 stuff</value></field>
        <field name='2'><value>B.2 stuff</value></field>
        <field name='3'><value>B.3 stuff</value></field>
    </field>
</fields>");
doc.Dump("Original XML");

var xpath = "//fields/field[@name='F']/field[@name='1' or @name='2'] | //fields/field[@name='B']/field[@name='3']";
doc.XPathSelectElements(xpath).Dump("XPath Combined");

var desired = XDocument.Parse(@"
<fields>
    <field name='F'>
        <field name='1'><value>F.1 stuff</value></field>
        <field name='2'><value>F.2 stuff</value></field>
    </field>
    <field name='B'>
        <field name='3'><value>B.3 stuff</value></field>
    </field>
</fields>");
desired.Dump("Desired Filtered XML");
```

EDIT: I completely missed XML Transforms - thank you for the solution!  Here's the solution you can paste into LINQPad to see it working:

```
var filterString = @"@name=""F""]/field[@name=""0""]  | field[@name=""B""]/field[not(@name=""3"")";
var xslFmt = @"
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0'
 xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration='yes' indent='yes'/>

 <xsl:template match='node()|@*'>
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select='node()|@*'/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  'field[{0}]
  '/>
</xsl:stylesheet>";
var xslMarkup = string.Format(xslFmt, filterString);

var xmlTree = XDocument.Parse(@"
<fields>
    <field name='F'>
        <field name='0'><value>F.0 stuff</value></field>
        <field name='1'><value>F.1 stuff</value></field>
        <field name='2'><value>F.2 stuff</value></field>
    </field>
    <field name='B'>
        <field name='0'><value>B.0 stuff</value></field>
        <field name='1'><value>B.1 stuff</value></field>
        <field name='2'><value>B.2 stuff</value></field>
        <field name='3'><value>B.3 stuff</value></field>
    </field>
</fields>");
xmlTree.Dump("Original XML");

// Code from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675186.aspx
var newTree = new XDocument();
using (var writer = newTree.CreateWriter()) {
    // Load the style sheet.
    var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslt.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xslMarkup)));

    // Execute the transform and output the results to a writer.
    xslt.Transform(xmlTree.CreateReader(), writer);
}

newTree.Dump("Transformed XML");
```

Comment: what are the criteria to get from your original XML to the "filtered" one?? Which XML nodes do you want to see, which do you want to "filter" out ??

Comment: Would XSLT be the right answer here?

Comment: Very detailed question, but it is still not so clear how to get from input to output. What criteria do apply?

Comment: You find the criteria in the code! But to me there is still no question.

Comment: @marc_s, 0xA3: the criteria are actually quite clear from the XPath expression... the OP wants the resulting XML elements in their original context, not as a flat list of XML element

Comment: @0xA3: Look at the definition of the `xpath` variable. It's all there.

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: those "criteria" seems to be a bit odd - it doesn't seem to be any similarity between the two sets of nodes he wants selected..... just seems very odd and arbitrary..... more like a random selection than an application of a filter criteria......

Comment: @dprice: XPath is a hosted language for selecting XML nodes. If you want to transform your document you have to use DOM methods (any framework library or API) or XSLT. If you want an easy example of XSLT, please retag.

Comment: @dprice: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution that uses an XSLT transformation. :)

Comment: As far as the arbitrary data, it's based on an issue we have working with Adobe XFDF data.  I tried to separate the underlying technologies from the actual XML filtering problem.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XPath is a query language and it cannot be used to produce a modified XML document**.

The technology which was especially designed for such transformations is called **XSLT**.

You can use the **[XDocument.CreateNavigator()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299124.aspx)** method and then use one of the overloads of the **[XslCompiledTransform.Transform()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163436.aspx)** method to carry out the transformation.

**The XSLT transformation itself is very simple**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "field[@name='F']/field[@name='0']
  |
   field[@name='B']/field[not(@name='3')]
  "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document, it produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<fields>
    <field name="F">
        <field name="1">
            <value>F.1 stuff</value>
        </field>
        <field name="2">
            <value>F.2 stuff</value>
        </field>
    </field>
    <field name="B">
        <field name="3">
            <value>B.3 stuff</value>
        </field>
    </field>
</fields>
```